# A term for functions whose integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is finite

Tags: terminology, improper-integrals

Is there a term (e.g. adjective) for functions whose integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is finite?

"$f$ is a _______ function implies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is finite."

Comment: "Integrable functions"?

Comment: @kimchilover The function $f(x)=1$ is Riemann integrable but does not satisfy the condition in question here. Or is there a different sense of "integrable"?

Comment: Indeed, the sense of the word "integrable" here is that of it's integral over $\Bbb R$ being finite, or perhaps more accurately the integral of the absolute value of the function being finite.  [The function-space of Lebesgue integrable functions is notated as $L^1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces).

Comment: As for the case of $f(x)=1$, it is integrable over any finite interval (*$\int_a^bf(x)dx = b-a$*), however it is not what I would call "integrable (*over the whole of $\Bbb R$*)".

Comment: $f$ is a $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx \in \mathbb R$ function implies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is finite.

Comment: Though "$f$ is an $L^1$ function" actually means $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\,dx$ is finite - so for example, $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not $L^1$ even though it does have a finite improper integral.